# Cómo refrescar un Fragment con swipeRefreshLayout

Tags: java, android

Tengo un Fragment al cual le he incluido SwipeRefreshLayout. Quisiera saber cómo puedo hacer para que en el evento `onRefresh` de SwipeRefreshLayout me recargue todo mi Fragment en donde ejecuto un `ListView`. Gracias.

FechasFragment.java

```
...

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fechas, container, false);

    swipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.swiperefresh);

    swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
    swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            //Código que debería refrescar este mismo fragment
            swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
        }
    });


    queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(v.getContext());
    String url = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
            try {
                for ( int item = 0; item < response.length(); item++ ) {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(item);
                    fechas.add(new Fechas(
                            jsonObject.getString("id"),
                            jsonObject.getString("nombre_lugar"),
                            jsonObject.getString("nombre_pais"),
                            jsonObject.getString("thumbnail"),
                            jsonObject.getString("fecha")
                    ));
                }

                ListView listView = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.listView);
                ArrayAdapter<Fechas> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(v.getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, fechas);
                listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

                listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                        //Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), fechas.get(position).getId(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), FechaActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("id", fechas.get(position).getId());
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });

                MyAdapterFechas myAdapterFechas = new MyAdapterFechas(v.getContext(), R.layout.fragment_fechas, fechas);
                listView.setAdapter(myAdapterFechas);

                swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);

            } catch(JSONException e) {

            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    });

    queue.add(jsonArrayRequest);

    return v;
}

...
```

Comment: Necesitas refrescar tu fragment?

Answer (score 1):

Debido a que estas usando `Volley`, en el método `onRefresh()` simplemente llama la petición ya que ahí ya se esta llamando `swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);`, no tienes que realizarlo en dos ocasiones :

```
swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {

         //Llamar petición Volley

        }
    });
```

y en el método